# Firebase new user accounts without having access to the app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am currently deploying an iOS and Android App to friends in the Beta Stage, so I know who is able to sign up. Today I discovered 4 new accounts created with Google Sign in, even tough I didn't distribute my beta-links to anyone other than people I know.

How is this possible? Furthermore on each SignUp a profile object is created in the firestore database which didn't happen with these 4 accounts?

Do you have any idea, how someone could sign up, without having access to the app? If it helps all the mails followed the same scheme: namelastName.5digits@gmail.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely those accounts were created by the [Google Play pre-launch check](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports) that automatically runs when you upload the app to the Play Store. Since these tests exercise your actual app, that would also explain how the profiles in Firestore were created.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a very logical answer to the occurrence. What is uncommon is that in Firestore no profiles were created, even tough they should have been. I assume Google is able to create accounts while somehow avoiding my code logic that creates the object in Firestore?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I _thought_ the accounts were created by using your app, but could definitely be wrong about that.